# How to filter FQL queries with fields that are not indexable

Tags: facebook-fql

The FQL query below results in a **NoIndexFunctionException** because **'current_location'** is not indexable.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()%20OR%20uid%20AND%20current_location%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1=me())&access_token=CCAAC...
```

Are there any alternatives for filtering non indexable fields?

Comment: There is no way for doing it. check out this answer by facebook developer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821969/how-could-i-use-fql-to-query-all-the-events-without-using-indexable-column-which/5824449#5824449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no alternatives for filtering non indexable fields, Ibrahim Faour, a Facebook employee has explained the technical reasoning behind indexes in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824449/321505).